# Copying file to device file in Linux if everything is a file

Tags: linux, terminal, command

Basically I am trying to learn Linux.

In Linux everything is a file. Even devices? which is like a fact. Then how can I access specific stream (stdout) of device (open file like display device) and paint something like image. I like to know what if I copy image from from a disk and paste it to display device (Specifically display device and not termninal, Like something painted on display). Is it right understanding

if so then would it work, something like following command

```
   cp fwd.txt opened_Display_Device_File
```

or

```
   echo "hello" >> Opened_Display_Device_File
```

and if its possible then what will be the exact command?

Comment: "In Linux everything is a file." That is not true. Some things are accessed through a file-like interface, but that's far from everything.

Answer (score 1):

"Everything is a file" is a dogma that is regularly taught. Not all devices have mappings to files; and those that do often have interfaces that are not particularly file-like.

However, display devices often *are* file-like, at least so far as routine drawing operations are concerned. Many Linux systems offer framebuffer devices that can be read and written much like 'ordinary' files. These devices usually have names like `/dev/fb0`. You can use utilities like `dd` to copy a framebuffer file to a regular file on disk, or to copy the file on disk back to the framebuffer.

However, the file format of a framebuffer file is not particularly intuitive -- it's very unlikely to be a regular graphics file format. In addition, the framebuffer device will have other ways to interface with applications other than simple file reads and writes. For example, there are device-specific `ioctl()` calls for setting things like display resolution and refresh rate.

So, yes, *many* Linux devices have file-like interfaces, but some are more file-like than others.